# Definitive way to do three-column layout in CSS

Tags: css

I have a really, really simple CSS question that has already been asked here a thousand times already in different forms, and seems to have no definitive answer.

I just want to create three columns on an HTML page, using CSS. Doesn't matter about fixed-width versus liquid: just need three columns.

Here's a complete HTML page:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="left" style="float:left; width:300px;">
<h3>Column 1</h3>
</div>
<div id="right" style="float:right; width:300px;">
<h3>Column 3</h3>
</div>
<div id="middle">
<h3>Column 2</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, at least, this is pushing the left & right columns down below the middle. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- float is sensitive to order. Put the left, then middle, then right.
- Have you tried floating the middle section too?

You might try this

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="left" style="float:left; width:300px;border:1px solid black;">
    <h3>Column 1</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="middle" style='float:left;width:600px;border:1px solid black;'>
    <h3>Column 2</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="right" style="float:left; width:300px;border:1px solid black;">
    <h3>Column 3</h3>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/Xu5c6/

just float everything left, and have the columns flow in the normal order in your HTML.

```
<div id="left">
  <h3>Column 1</h3>
</div>
<div id="middle">
  <h3>Column 2</h3>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <h3>Column 3</h3>
</div>
```

css:

```
#left {
 background-color: red;  
 float:left;
 width:200px;
}

#middle {
 background-color: salmon; 
 float:left;
 width:200px;
}

#right {
 background-color: pink;  
 float:left; 
 width:200px;
}
```

if you don't want them to wrap, you can wrap a container div around them, or use

```
body {
 width: 600px; /*combined width of three columns*/
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/Xu5c6/1/